# Quick question on plugging in the limits of integration in this integral for finding the surface area

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

[image]

**My Question:**

In the image above, I am computing the integral whose answer will give me the surface area of some object.

I noticed that when I choose different values for arcsin(-1): -90° or 270°, the final answer for the integral will be different, respectively, -π or π.

So my question is why is the  -π/2 used for arcsin(-1) instead of using 3π/2? If I use 3π/2, would it be allowed? Since surface area can't be negative, and if I were to use 3π/2, would I just need to indicate my answer as π instead of -π, or can only -π/2 be used for the value of arcsin(-1) for some reason?

**Edit: This question is resolved**

Comment: We use principle values when dealing with Inverse Trigonometric Functions.

Comment: What's principle values?

Comment: The range of $y = \arcsin(x)$ is $y \in \left[-\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]$.

Comment: both  -π/2 and 3π/2 are equivalent for the value of arcsin(-1), so my question is why can't I use  3π/2 . This will give me -π which is incorrect as the answer is just π

Comment: Please read this :) : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

Comment: Here's another example: you can't use $\arcsin(-1) = \dfrac{3\pi}{2}$ for the same the same reason you can’t use $\sqrt{4} = -2$.

Comment: @KM101 that doesn't answer the question tho... (Edit: Gotcha)

Comment: I already did. (Look at my first comment.) Just wanted to give a related example.

Comment: I forget some properties of inverse functions, but if I remember correctly, is the value  -π/2 taken for arcsin(-1) because sin(x) on its own is not 1-1 function, so restricting its domain to [−π/2,π/2], will give its inverse, since only 1-1 function can have inverses? This the reason?

Comment: Yes, that's why.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the angles $x$ where $\sin(x) = -1$, then you will have infinite answers... you will have:

$$x=-\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi,k\in\mathbb Z$$

But, $\arcsin(-1)$ is always $-\frac{\pi}{2}$. 
It is a matter of how $\arcsin$ function is defined.

[image]